# How to implement a caching server?

Tags: architecture, redis, client-server, memcached, soa

I have a scenario today where about 50,000 windows clients (users) continuously poll a standalone server regularly throughout the day. For security reasons I am not mentioning what the server is doing, but it is a third part vender product with in-premise installation. So I as a programmer don't have much control over how it manages different requests but we are aware there are few performance issues when using its provided APIs. Also this product is indispensable for various reasons and its vast functionalities and we cannot move to a different product and even if we move the main problem I am about to mention does not get solved.

We have built a client application that is used by users within our organization and this application apart from other things needs to make a API call on the service I mentioned above. Now we find that this call is expensive for certain heavy use cases. I am sure the server has some sort of inbuilt cache logic implemented but given the varying fidelity of the input query to this API it would be of not much use.

Again the main function of this API is to query against a global database and return a unique item. For eg:=>

```
//Return all names in database that begin with the user entered text.
NameCollection GetNamesBeginningWith(string inputText);
```

Now this is an example and not the original API.

Now I am thinking of introducing another cache server between all the clients and this main server. I recently learnt about 'redis' and am planning to use it for caching all the records lets say max 200,000. So initially from my redis instance I will read all records of that particular table and have those records in the cache and then all my clients would now talk to my redis instance instead of communicating directly to the main server for this use case.

I am primarily a client side developer with only basic knowledge of the server side nuances. Am I going in the right path ?

Is 'redis' a recommended solution ?

Also the data I am taking about is volatile as in it might change once a month or some data might never change for a long time so to be safe I am planning to schedule a job that refreshes the cache every morning. I have never done something like this before. So I ask the community if this is a recommended approach ?

In that case how do I refresh the cache without the end users noticing it ?

Answer (score 2):

As Tom already said your solution is OK in general and Redis is a good choice for it. I just want to draw your attention to the availability problem. From your question it looks like all your clients will be reading data directly from Redis. The problem is that Redis server or its agent may go down for a number of reasons, besides some server maintanance tasks will require a restart. If you need your client up and running 24/7 you will have to deal with it. The most common solution is to configure Redis replication with at least one slave. Please note this will require some Redis administrative skills and most lickely extra expenses for the infrastructure. Looks a bit complex doesn't it? If I were you I woudn't go this way and would start with simple lazy loading first. You can always CHECK your Redis cache first and then if it's empty or unavailable read the data from the API in the old way. In this case if redis is down your client will be online but just slow. When Redis is up you won't have to touch the API at all.

> In that case how do I refresh the cache without the end users noticing
>   it ?

I don't see a problem here. Your job should just read data from the API and update Redis by schedule. Redis will handle all concurrency stuff.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Am I going in the right path ?

I think in general your approach would work especially if the data only changes month by month and not second by second.

> Is 'redis' a recommended solution ?

No doubt recommended by Redis and it's happy users. If you need a cache, sure, Redis will work. Memcached also.

> In that case how do I refresh the cache without the end users noticing
>   it ?

Many cache technologies have built in mechanisms to allow you to synchronize data changes in the source data to all the nodes which comprise the cache in real time and without interruption. I know this is the case with Oracle Coherence. I don't know if Redis supports this but would be surprised if it did not.